# Wndows 7 hard drive is corrupt

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, boot

Few days before, my PC has stopped working.  The scenario was as follows:

1. Windows loading files
2. Microsoft Corporation logo
3. Message alert:

   > Windows cannot repair this computer automatically
   >
   > a) Send info about this problem
   >     b) Don't send
4. When I click any of above options, I get another message as below

   > If you have recently attached a device to this computer, such as a camera or portable music player, remove it and restart your computer.  If you continue to see this message, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.
5. After all this I decided for fresh installation
6. I inserted a bootable Windows 7 disk, List of drivers are listed for fresh installation.
7. Here I format all my drives (C, D, E)
8. After that when I try to set the size of disk space (partition for C drive), I get message

   > Hard drive is corrupted

From here, I don't know what to do. How can I resolve this issue? Is it a hard disk error or OS error?

I tried following this: [Windows XP fails to start, and, while trying to reinstall it, installation says "hard drive is corrupt", but I don't think it is](https://superuser.com/questions/467129/Windows-xp-fails-to-start-and-while-trying-to-reinstall-it-installation-says)

Comment: What *exactly* are you doing when you get the hard drive is corrupted message? And what *exactly* is the text of the message? Is it precisely "hard drive is corrupted"? (And not "hard drive corrupt", "hard drive corruption detected" or something similar?)

Comment: It's "hard drive corrupt"

Comment: @imdev27 - That is the EXACT message because your question indicates something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I think your hard drives has some bad clusters at the beginning of the drive. You can do a disk check by booting from a medium like a DVD or USB and run a check disk.
Open de command utility and type `chkdsk C: /B`.
This may take a while, but it will tell you everything you need to know. If you can't figure out the results you can post the result here.

If your hard drive contains bad clusters, you cannot use it to install your OS on it. If I were you I wouldn't do any thing with the hard drive.

EDIT:
check [this](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=6565) link to see how you can run check disk at startup.

Comment: how to run check disk at the start of PC? Is it possible in safe mode ?

Comment: See my edit, the link should provide you the proper information

Comment: In System Recovery Options, I get only one option "StartUp Repair". how can i use command prompt ?

Comment: If you follow the steps at the link I gave you should be able to run command prompt. If that option is somehow disabled, I can't help you further, try google.